# CSS text-transform except certain character/string

Tags: css

Is there a way I can make an exception to `text-transform: lowercase;` such that the word '`I`' (i.e. a space, followed by the letter I, followed by a space) would still be rendered as a capital?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can wrap the `I` inside a span tag, you can override the case.

```css
.text {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.text span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">All lowercase BUT <span>I</span> is uppercase</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's essentially what I'm doing right now with:
`.pronounI {text-transform: uppercase !important;}`

and `<span class="pronounI">I</span>`
I was hoping there may be a way to automate this in CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS cannot select text nodes. No vanilla CSS solution for it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. At least I now know to stop looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p {
   text-transform: lowercase;
}

p::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```